# Waypoints and toggling classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am unable to get Waypoints working with my tabbed sidebar. When the bottom of the #four element is in view the .active class should activate for the #details element, but for some reason it does not. My code looks like this

```
$('#four').waypoint(function() {
  $('#details').toggleClass('active');
}, {
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

Example with issue: http://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/Nqrwqv
(Waypoints and Font-Awesome are both called in the setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery must be called before Waypoints. Rookie mistake.